# Comparing two arrays in C++ through cin

Tags: c++, arrays

Ok I try to do something like this

```
string account[3]={"asr123","cbg567","oit777"};
int  pins[3]={1234,4567,7890};

string userAccount;
int userPin;

cin >> userAccount;
cin >> userPin;
```

and now how to make it so that account "asr123" and pins "1234" are "together" that 1234 is pin for that account? Any  hints, I tried with for lop but any of those pins

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "together"? In what context are you checking them?

Comment: Why not use map instead

Comment: No! That's a so badly asked basic question, nothing showed about attempts and particular obstaclas with them, no ...

Answer (score 2):

You should use map instead, it will be easy to code and efficient.

```
map<string, int> passwords;

passwords["asr123"]=12345; // do like this for all pairs

string userAccount;
int userPin;

cin >> userAccount;
cin >> userPin;

if(passwords[userAccount]==userPin){
  cout<<"OK";
}
else{
  cout<<"incorrect";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look up a string with acspecific ID you can use an std::map. You can later add the pairs (3 of them in your case) one by one and later easily look your strings up with ints.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make sure that the two values the user inputs matches up with two values in your two arrays.

A linear-time solution would be to just loop through the two arrays, although **this is not a good way to check for user login**.

You would write something like the following.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (userAccount.compare(account[i]) == 0 && userPin == pins[i]) {
        // Do something because there was a match.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for suggestion and advices. I can't use map since we haven't reach it in our class yet. Our teacher wants it the way I described above. this is what I found in my notebook. Like I mentioned above, two arrays, and then forloop. for(.......) { if(cust_acct==account[i] )} I think that is "i" he wrote. and then bellow that && empty space = empty space. He didn't want to tell us everything that is why there is empty space. I think merlin uses something similar. Thanks

Comment: @Nac, If it is just for an assignment, then the solution I outlined above should get you close.

Comment: Yeah I'll try  like that merlin. thanks for help. I will update later  how it goes.  Just one question, why do you put 0, I mean here account[i])== 0 ? what if user puts second "element" / second account as his? won't that affect it?